# Does @Transactional annotation work if autocommit is true?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Would roll back work if auto commit is turned on? if not then what is the implications of turning auto commit off?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {ManagerException.class})
public myMethod()....{
    System.out.printLn(my_spring_stored_procedure.getDataSource()
            .getConnection().getAutoCommit()) //true
    ....
    try {
        result = this.my_spring_stored_procedure.execute(params);
    }catch(DataAccessException e){
        throw new ManagerException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: By definition, no, but Spring may be able to disable auto-commit to make this work.  I'm curious to see answers.  +1 good question

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you check the code, you will find that when the spring uses this kind of way to do the transaction. If your config is that auto commit is true, then it will change it to false and after the transaction it will change it to true.